# The file is possibly corrupt. The file header checksum does not match the computed checksum

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, crash

I had a laptop ([Compaq C700](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compaq_Presario#Notebook_series), 2 GB RAM, 160 GB hard disk drive) installed with Windows XP. When it was in standby mode due to power interruption, it switched off and after restarting it showed **NTLDR missing**.

Then I tried installing Windows 7 and while installing after the first reboot, it showed the message:

> The File is possibly corrupt. The file header checksum does not match the computed checksum.

I tried to install it again by formatting the whole hard disk and took a backup too before installation. I even did a hard disk test in the [BIOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS) and it was showing OK.

I went to HP's service center 45 days ago (very poor service, the laptop is still there) and they are saying my hard disk needs to be replaced because it has crashed, but I don't think it has crashed. The problem may be something else. What could be the reason and possible solution?

Comment: The problems you have can be explained by a failing hdd.

Comment: It could be HDD, but it may also be a problem with your installation media. Were you installing Windows from a DVD or a pendrive?

Answer (score 1):

Check the smart stats on the drive using a [live CD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_CD) of some sort, like [Parted Magic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parted_Magic)
and see if the drive reports a mechanical failure of some sort. You might want to connect the drive to another system and attempt a `chkdsk /f` on it, to check for bad blocks.

Comment: thanks Frank I'll follow your suggestion. In recovery mode of Windows 7, I had done **chkdsk /f** but there was not any bad blocks too. One more thing I would like to tell you that while installing windows 7 I had taken backup of the data in my external hard disk as well. So data was there. Does that mean some of the blocks are corrupted?

Comment: @Chetan - Yes, it means your hdd crashes and there are bad sectors ( the reason for the crash ) you should replace the hdd.